# Why isn't getopt working if sys.argv is passed fully?

Tags: python, getopt

If I'm using this with `getopt`:

```
import getopt
import sys

opts,args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv,"a:bc")
print opts
print args
```

`opts` will be empty. No tuples will be created. If however, I'll use `sys.argv[1:]`, everything works as expected. I don't understand why that is. Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first element of `sys.argv` (`sys.argv[0]`) is the name of the script currently being executed. Because this script name is (likely) not a valid argument (and probably doesn't begin with a `-` or `--` anyway), `getopt` does not recognize it as an argument. Due to the nature of how `getopt` works, when it sees something that is not a command-line flag (something that does not begin with `-` or `--`), it stops processing command-line options (and puts the rest of the arguments into `args`), because it assumes the rest of the arguments are items that will be handled by the program (such as filenames or other "required" arguments).

Answer (score 7):

It's by design. Recall that sys.argv[0] is the running program name, and getopt doesn't want it.

From the docs:

> Parses command line options and
>   parameter list. args is the argument
>   list to be parsed, without the leading
>   reference to the running program.
>   Typically, this means sys.argv[1:].
>   options is the string of option
>   letters that the script wants to
>   recognize, with options that require
>   an argument followed by a colon (':';
>   i.e., the same format that Unix
>   getopt() uses).

http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html