# Cannot handle parameters with getopt python

Tags: python, getopt

In order to offer options to  my python script, I want to introduce some parameters. I found that the better way to do this in python is with getopt, but once I run my script it doesn't do anything. Please help me!!!. This is my code:

```
def main(argv):
     try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hi:o:t', ['help', 'input=', 'output='])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
            usage()
            sys.exit(2)
            file = None
            outfile = None
    for opt, arg in opts:
            if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
                    usage()
                    sys.exit(2)
            elif opt in ('-i', '--input'):
                    file = arg
            elif opt in ('-o', '--output'):
                    outfile = arg
            elif opt == '-t':
                    maininfo(file,outfile)
            else:
                    usage()
                    sys.exit(2)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: could you tell me how does it not work first before you ask? What is the error msg?

Comment: Once it fixed the indentation on the `try:` line, I found that this worked as I expected. [`file`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) is a built-in class in Python, so you should call your variable something else.

Comment: @Johnsyweb thanks, I change file for infile but it doesn't work. And there is no error msg.. :(

Comment: @Alejandro: No error msg? well you can first try to print some debug message to see what's going on first, e.g. at the start of the function, does it get your input argument?

Comment: aaahhh I know what is my problem, I am trying to run python in batch mode and I didn't include this option. How could include the python option -b in my code???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest adding more logging. Not only will this help you out now, it'll help out whoever uses your script in future.

```
def main(argv):
    filename = None
    outfile = None
    call_maininfo = False
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hi:o:t', ['help', 'input=', 'output='])
        if not opts:
            print 'No options supplied'
            usage()
    except getopt.GetoptError, e:
        print e
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
            usage()
            sys.exit(2)
        elif opt in ('-i', '--input'):
            filename = arg
        elif opt in ('-o', '--output'):
            outfile = arg
        elif opt == '-t':
            call_maininfo = True
        else:
            usage()
            sys.exit(2)

    print 'Processed options [{0}] and found filename [{1}] and outfile [{2}]'.format(
            ', '.join(argv),
            filename,
            outfile,
            )

    if call_maininfo:
        print 'Calling maininfo()'
        maininfo(filename, outfile)
```

I also moved the call to `maininfo()` out of the loop as you could supply `-t` before the filenames!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)(old version, will be deprecated after python 2.7) or  [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) ( a new version), which are standard python module parsing arguments.

Hope it helps this first

Comment: this could be the problem? that getopt is obsolete??

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540399/2542738

Basically, you need to remove `'python'` from `opts` as it is the first element of the list `opts`: `opts.pop(0)` and then you should be fine.